# Is there a method to find each maximum value before changing to another index value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get the max for each index before its changing to another index. As shown in below dataframe example

| index_a | column_b | all_max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | - |
| 0 | 20 | - |
| 0 | 30 | 30 |
| 1 | 50 | 50 |
| 1 | 30 | - |
| 1 | 20 | - |
| 1 | 10 | - |
| 0 | 70 | 70 |
| 0 | 60 | - |
| 0 | 40 | - |

... (so on)

but instead i get results like this using the function i mentioned below

| index_a | column_b | all_max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 70 |
| 0 | 20 | 70 |
| 0 | 30 | 70 |
| 1 | 50 | 70 |
| 1 | 30 | 70 |
| 1 | 20 | 70 |
| 1 | 10 | 70 |
| 0 | 70 | 70 |
| 0 | 60 | 70 |
| 0 | 40 | 70 |

... (so on)

the index row is not fixed repetition, some have more 1s or 0s.

I have tried using the `.max()` function but it only provide me for the max value inside the Column B

```
for i, row in df.iloc[:-1].iterrows():
   if df['index_a'][i] == 0:
     df['all_max'][i] = df['column_b'][i].max()
   else:
     df['all_max'][i] = df['column_b'][i].max()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.tranform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) on successive groups to get the max per group as a broadcasted Series, then identify the max rows and assign the value with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), else a `-`:

```
group = df['index_a'].ne(df['index_a'].shift()).cumsum()
m = df.groupby(group)['column_b'].transform('max').eq(df['column_b'])

df['all_max'] = df['column_b'].where(m, '-')
```

Output:

```
   index_a  column_b all_max
0        0        10       -
1        0        20       -
2        0        30      30
3        1        50      50
4        1        30       -
5        1        20       -
6        1        10       -
7        0        70      70
8        0        60       -
9        0        40       -
```

Answer (score 0):

If need all maximum values per consecutive groups use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) by groups by compare shifted values with cumulative sums, compare by original `column_b` and assign `-` if no match in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
m = (df.groupby(df['index_a'].ne(df['index_a'].shift()).cumsum())['column_b']
       .transform('max')
       .eq(df['column_b']))
 
df['all_max'] = df['column_b'].where(m, '-')

print (df)
   index_a  column_b all_max
0        0        10       -
1        0        20       -
2        0        30      30
3        1        50      50
4        1        30       -
5        1        20       -
6        1        10       -
7        0        70      70
8        0        60       -
9        0        40       -
```

But if need match only first maximal value per same groups use:

```
i = df.groupby(df['index_a'].ne(df['index_a'].shift()).cumsum())['column_b'].idxmax()

df['all_max'] = '-'
df.loc[i, 'all_max'] = df['column_b']

print (df)
   index_a  column_b all_max
0        0        10       -
1        0        20       -
2        0        30      30
3        1        50      50
4        1        30       -
5        1        20       -
6        1        10       -
7        0        70      70
8        0        60       -
9        0        40       -
```

You can see difference in changed data:

```
print (df)
   index_a  column_b
0        0        10
1        0        30 <- 2 maximums per first 0 group
2        0        30
3        1        50
4        1        30
5        1        20
6        1        10
7        0        70
8        0        60
9        0        40

m = (df.groupby(df['index_a'].ne(df['index_a'].shift()).cumsum())['column_b']
       .transform('max')
       .eq(df['column_b']))
 
df['all_max1'] = df['column_b'].where(m, '-')


i = df.groupby(df['index_a'].ne(df['index_a'].shift()).cumsum())['column_b'].idxmax()

df['all_max2'] = '-'
df.loc[i, 'all_max2'] = df['column_b']
```

---

```
print (df)
   index_a  column_b all_max1 all_max2
0        0        10        -        -
1        0        30       30       30
2        0        30       30        -
3        1        50       50       50
4        1        30        -        -
5        1        20        -        -
6        1        10        -        -
7        0        70       70       70
8        0        60        -        -
```

Answer (score 0):

Create virtual groups to distinguish same identifier in `index_a` column:

```
df['all_max'] = (df.groupby(df['index_a'].ne(df['index_a'].shift()).cumsum())['column_b']
                   .transform('max'))
print(df)

# Output
   index_a  column_b  all_max
0        0        10       30
1        0        20       30
2        0        30       30
3        1        50       50
4        1        30       50
5        1        20       50
6        1        10       50
7        0        70       70
8        0        60       70
9        0        40       70
```